# parsing json and getting exception, reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b1c7630

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to get a value for a particular key from a dictionary but i get a `[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

```
- (void)listCaredMembersSuccessResponse:(NSDictionary *)response {
[self hideActivityView];

 if ([[response valueForKey:@"status"] caseInsensitiveCompare:NSLocalizedString(@"SUCCESS", nil)] == NSOrderedSame) {
   NSDictionary *mainDict = [response objectForKey:@"data"];
   NSArray *detailsArray = [mainDict objectForKey:@"Text"];
   [appDelegate.proxiesListArr addObjectsFromArray:[ParserManager parseListCaredMembers:detailsArray]];
 } else {
   [[ClassObjects sharedCenter] showCustomAlert:@"" Message:NSLocalizedString(@"PROXIES_FAILURERESPONSE", nil)];
  }
```

This is my json response:

```
{"Status":"Success","data":[{"Alias":"1-0","ID":80,"Icon":"","Items":[],"Params":{},"Text”:”Text1”,”Type":"group","Width":"170"},{"Alias":"1-1","ID":8000102,"Icon":"","Items":[],"Params":{},"Text”:”Text2”,”Type":"group","Width":"170"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have a `NSArray` not an `NSDictionary`. The `NSArray` has a count of 1 and contains an `NSDictionary`.

> this line is wrong `NSArray *detailsArray = [mainDict objectForKey:@"Text"];`

```
NSArray *wrapper= [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];

for (NSDictionary *temp in wrapper) {

   NSString *text=[temp objectForKey:@"Text"]; //Text may be NSString type


    // THE REST OF YOUR CODE
}
```

**Update**

```
if ([[response valueForKey:@"status"] caseInsensitiveCompare:NSLocalizedString(@"SUCCESS", nil)] == NSOrderedSame) {

NSArray *mainDict = [response objectForKey:@"data"];

  for (NSDictionary *temp in mainDict) {

   NSString *text=[temp objectForKey:@"Text"]; //Text may be NSString type


    // THE REST OF YOUR CODE
}

}
```

Comment: @Anub.Karthik. i am change my code based on your answer now i got this exception: [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7bf819b0

Comment: in which line you are faceing the issue bro

Comment: NSDictionary *mainDict = [response objectForKey:@"data"];
         
    for (NSDictionary *temp in mainDict) {
   
        NSString *text = temp[@"Text"];
        
          NSMutableArray *detailsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        
         [detailsArray addObject:text];
        
         [appDelegate.proxiesListArr addObjectsFromArray:[ParserManager parseListCaredMembers:detailsArray]]; i am writing like this.. but i got issue in this line of code "[appDelegate.proxiesListArr addObjectsFromArray:[ParserManager parseListCaredMembers:detailsArray]];"

Comment: @user3201089 -- you are created in wrong answer , just wait I update my answer

Comment: in this line of code i got exception " [appDelegate.proxiesListArr addObjectsFromArray:[ParserManager parseListCaredMembers:detailsArray]];" exception is like this "[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae24770"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102764/discussion-between-user3201089-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: @Anub.Karthik now i got error like this bro [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ca31f20